# Unable to find .ssh/known_hosts file from the Mac terminal

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I am using Mac OS Mojave and connecting to the `*.pem`. I am trying to identify the `.ssh/known_hosts` file from the terminal to make a few edits. However, I do not see any file the whole folder which is empty. I can only see the `authorized_keys` file.

Is there a way to obtain the `.ssh/known_hosts` file?

Thank you.

Comment: How can the folder be empty if there is a `authorized_keys` present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in terminal ---> `nano .ssh/known_hosts` (with **sudo** if you wish to edit).

If the file isn't present means you could have ommited the "trust host" option upon first connnection. Try moving the .ssh folder elsewhere temporarly (i.e your desktop), relaunch a fresh terminal and SSH from fresh to see the first time prompts, and if the known_hosts file generates.

Ps: macOS is very picky when it comes to SSH public keys; i find it's much trickier than to carry your keys to a new install than on any other machine, not "plug & play".. be sure to backup before editing ;)